# How to spawn random 2D platforms that do not overlap in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm looking for a way to randomly spawn platforms that do not overlap with each other. All the tutorials I found on this topic are for an endless runner game type, and my project is not like that. So far I know how to spawn my platforms but I need those gaps between them. I'm a total begginer in Unity and C# so I'm looking for a simple code if possible.

My code now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class GameStateManager: MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject YellowPrefab;
    public int howManyYellow;

 void Start()
    { GameObject tmpYellow;

        for (int i = 0; i < howManyYellow; i++)
        {
            tmpYellow = Instantiate(YellowPrefab, new
                        Vector3(Random.Range(-50, 50), Random.Range(-
                        40, -17), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
 }
```

My platforms have box colliders used by platform effector, if that information is needed.

Edit:
If possible, it would be nice to be able to set max distance between the random platforms, but if it's something hard to do with that kind of code then it's OK without that:)

Comment: What kind of game is it? Is it grid based or free form? Top down or side scroll?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll not detecting other gameobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175470/physics2d-overlapcircleall-not-detecting-other-gameobjects)

Comment: @DetectivePikachu It's just a simple platformer game, space limited by colliders filled with random platforms, no grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `Physics2D.OverlapBox()` or related functions, depending on your needs.
With this you can check if your object's collider is overlapping with any other collider, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < howManyYellow; i++)
{
    tmpYellow = Instantiate(YellowPrefab, 
                            new Vector3(Random.Range(-50, 50), 
                            Random.Range(-40, -17), 0), 
                            Quaternion.identity);

    BoxCollider2D tmpYCollider = tmpYellow.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    tmpyCollider.enabled = false; // Disable object's own collider to prevent detecting itself

    // while collider overlaps, move your object somewhere else (e.g. 17 units up)
    while (Physics2D.OverlapBox(tmpYCollider.bounds.center, tmpYCollider.size, 0) != null)
    {
        tmpYellow.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 17));
        // or do something else
    }

    tmpyCollider.enabled = true; // enable the collider again
}
```

Comment: For some reason unity freezes when I try to run my game with this bit of code, but that might be an issue with my laptop. But I'll definitely try it on some other computer, cause it looks like something I might be looking for :)

Comment: No, it wasn't an issue with your laptop. I just found the problem and edited my answer accordingly.

The problem was that `OverlapBox()` detects the actual object you're trying to check for, which caused the while loop to loop forever. 
Now, there are several ways to prevent this. In my example I chose to disable the object's collider before checking and then enabling it again later.

But my code is still just an example, so you may want to look into the functions I'm using and change the code to your needs. :)

Comment: Now it works well, thanks! I really like how it works overall, but, the platforms spawns really far out of set boundaries... I tried to change how far they are moved after they overlap and narrowing down the random range where they are spawned, but nothing seems to work. I'll try to figure it out myself, but if you have any idea why it's like that then I'll appreciate any tips. Thanks again :D

Comment: Without knowing the rest of your code and your overall setup, it's hard to tell. I don't know how many platforms you are spawning and how you want them to spawn and be positioned. And there are so many other unknowns, like your unit size. So if 1 unit is set to 100 pixels in your project, my example value of 17 units would catapult your platforms out of the screen. In that case you would want to try e.g. 0.01 units instead of my 17.

Comment: I just realised it detects the colliders used to prevent the player to go too far left/right and stops the platforms from overlapping with those too. Thanks a lot, I'll use your code :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :) One interesting aspect for OverlapBox() and the related Overlap...() and Raycast() functions is the layerMask parameter. With it you can have more and better control over which colliders you will detect. I didn't include this in my answer to keep it simpler and less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to create a bunch of platforms randomly in the area of (-50,-40) -> (50,-17).

If you do not want a platform to be created in the same spot you need to keep track of the location that all of the platforms were placed in.

```
public GameObject YellowPrefab;
public int howManyYellow;
private List<Vector3> locations;

void Start()

locations = new List<Vector3>();
{ 
    GameObject tmpYellow;

    for (int i = 0; i < howManyYellow; i++)
    {
        bool hasItem = false;
         Vector3 tempLocation;
        do{
            tempLocation = new Vector3(Random.Range(-50, 50), Random.Range(-40, -17), 0);
            foreach (Vector3 item in locations)
            {
                if(tempLocation == item){

                    hasItem = true;
                }
            }
        } while(hasItem);
        locations.Add(tempLocation);

         tmpYellow = Instantiate(YellowPrefab, tempLocation, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it  is now fixed.

Comment: See also: `List<T>.Contains()`

Comment: Thanks :) , it works definitely better than my code, but for some reason the platforms still overlap sometimes. But not as much as before

Comment: Draco18s sorry about that, I would be using 'List<T>.Contains()' if the struct, Vector3, was created by me personally. This is due to not knowing if Vector3 properly implements ICollection to which Contains uses an overridden version of '.Equals()'. Unity probably does this correctly but I will not instinctively use '.Contains()' for this reason.